# How to get <tr> object via jQuery using one of cell content for example **Some Text**?

Tags: jquery

How to get `<tr>` object via jQuery using one of cell content for example  **Some Text**?

```
<tr style="border: 1px solid #07234B; border-collapse: collapse;">
 <td style="border: 1px solid #07234B; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
     Some text
 </td>
 <td style="border: 1px solid #07234B; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
     7/8/2012 
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("td:contains('Some text')").parent()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td').find('Some Text').parentUntil('tr');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/YYdCE/

```
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "Some text";
}).closest("tr");
```